# Every password fails on Devise Admin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed the first option to create an Admin role as recommended here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role

After that, I created a seed to populate the Admin Model:

```
Admin.create!([{email: "email@example.com"},
                  {password: "password"},
                  {password_confirmation: "password"}])
```

Admin Model

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
 devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :lockable 
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :admins
end
```

I tried to sign_in with this password at /admins/sign_in without sucess.

At the rails console I can see the Admin.first, so i don't have idea what im doing worng. Any idea?

Comment: can you post more code like your routes and admin model

Comment: I edited my question @Ren

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your syntax.  The bracket-types matter..  Right now you are trying to create an admin with an array `[ ]`, where your attributes are divided up into different objects in that array.

Try creating another admin, but this time without the square brackets`[ ]` and a single hash `{ }`:

```
Admin.create!({email: "email@example.com",
              password: "password",
              password_confirmation: "password"})
```

This way you are creating a single `Admin` object, with the attributes email, password, etc.

If you wanted to create multiple `Admins` all in one line of code, then you could use an array:

```
Admin.create!([{email: "email@example.com",
                  password: "password",
                  password_confirmation: "password"},
               {email: "differentadmin@example.com",
                  password: "foobar",
                  password_confirmation: "foobar"}])
```